# All Messages of Referenced Jar to Log File + Setting up Encoding of Log File to UTF-8 to display Japanese Characters (Log4j2)

Tags: java, log4j2

I have 2 questions regarding Log4j2.

1. How can I set that warnings and errors of referenced Jar files to output in the log file instead of the console? Currently, log statements in my application are being printed in the log file. But those messages from the referenced Jar files are being printed in the console instead.
2. How can I set Japanese characters to be printed in the generated logfile? Currently, I have set charset of layout but the output of Japanese characters are still in "?" or garbage characters.

This is my current property file:

```
    status = error
    name = PropertiesConfig
    
    property.filename = ${sys:user.home}\\myApp\\logs\\application.log
     
    filters = threshold
     
    filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
    filter.threshold.level = debug
    #filter.threshold.level = info
     
    appenders = rolling
     
    appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
    appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
    appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
    appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:user.home}\\myApp\\logs\\log-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.zip
    appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
    appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
    appender.rolling.layout.charset = "UTF-8"
    appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
    appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
    appender.rolling.policies.size.size=1MB
    appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
    appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20
     
    loggers = rolling
     
    logger.rolling.name = org.mycom.myproj.tools.myapp
    logger.rolling.level = all
    logger.rolling.additivity = false
    logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
    
    rootLogger.level = all
    rootLogger.appenderRefs = rolling
    rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

Comment: Did you try to remove the double quotes in your charset definition?

Comment: @Heri Removing the double quotes actually worked! Can't believe I didn't try that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean 'external third party libraries' by 'referenced jar files'. Libraries usually use a logger abstraction like apache.commons.logging or slfj4 for issuing its log outputs.

You need to add an additional dependency which bridges these log outputs correctly to your log4j2-Logger. e.g. "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.7".

If you do not provide such a bridge the log abstraction framework might do default initialization (which probably logs to console).

Comment: This worked! Yes, I was referring to "external third party libraries". This worked for the major libraries, but cant get it to work for the warnings of Tika library. I think I just need to search the logging that they used for this library.

Anyway, thanks mate!